# "error: process didn't exit successfully" when initialising KMeans struct

Tags: rust

I am trying to use the [kmeans](https://crates.io/crates/kmeans) crate on the nightly channel:

```
use kmeans::*;

fn main() {
    let (sample_cnt, sample_dims, k, max_iter) = (20000, 200, 4, 2500);

    // Generate some random data
    let mut samples = vec![0.0f64; sample_cnt * sample_dims];
    samples.iter_mut().for_each(|v| *v = rand::random());

    // Calculate kmeans, using kmean++ as initialization-method
    let kmean = KMeans::new(samples, sample_cnt, sample_dims);
}
```

However when initialising the `KMeans` struct I get a runtime error:

```
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\my_kmeans.exe` (exit code: 0xc0000374, STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION)
```

I'm not sure if this is an error in my environment/code or if it's a bug in the crate and whether an issue should be created. What are the possible causes of this error specifically with the kmeans crate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this is an error in my environment/code or if it's a bug in the crate

You did not write any `unsafe` code. Therefore, heap corruption **cannot be your code's fault.** It could be:

- A bug in the unsafe code in `kmeans`.

  Note that even if you passed incorrect arguments to `kmeans`, it's still not your fault. This is part of the foundation of Rust's safety: non-`unsafe` functions are safe to call.
- A bug in the Rust compiler.

  You're using nightly `rustc` so there could be a bug that hasn't been caught yet. Consider using the stable compiler instead. It looks like `kmeans` requires nightly but that should be counted a reason to not use it.
- Something in your environment is interfering with the correct execution of the program (e.g. injecting code into the running program, that does something unexpected).
- Unusual compiler options that result in miscompilation or incompatibility. Presumably you did not do anything like that.

Comment: I'm leaning towards it being a bug in the kmeans crate. Thanks for the clear answer :)